# How to display data from specific database rows that matches a specfic value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website that my friends and I can use to create random teams for when we want to do a team vs team match in a video game like CS:GO. I currently have a mysql database with a users table. In this table are their gamertags, the team they're in, and other things like their name and emails. There is also a login system so everyone can only change their own team.

I have the team selection part figured out and working. When someone presses a button, a field in their database row gets updated with a 1 or 2. 1 stand for team 1, 2 for team 2. This is all working fine. The problem is that after they press the button I want to display every teammate and I can't get this working.

I tried using `while` loops, the problem is that the page is full of gamertags because it's a `while` loop. And it's also the gamertag from just one person and not all of their teammates.

So in short, how can I display every gamertag that has the value of `lanteam = 1` or `lanteam = 2` in the database.

This is the code that I currently have. When this gets run, it correctly changes the text from team 1, your captain is Martijn to team 2, your captain is Raoul if their team is updated. Only the gamertag always stays the same. It's always the one from the member that is the highest of the table. It also doesn't matter if he's in team 1 or 2. This is probably a really easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

```
require '../includes/dbh.inc.php';
$sql = "SELECT lanteam, gamertag FROM users WHERE lanteam=1 OR lanteam=2";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row["lanteam"] == 1){
            echo "You're member of team 1, your captain is Martijn";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Your teammates: <br>";
            echo $row['gamertag'];
            echo "<br>";
        }else{
            echo "You're member of team 1, your captain is Raoul";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Your teammates: <br>";
            echo $row['gamertag'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Your query will find all the users who are on either team 1 or 2. You then fetch the first row from that list and output based on it. AFAICT, this should always be outputting not only the same gamertag, but the same captain.

Answer (score 0):

I found the sollution,

If I do it like the code below, it outputs only the gamertags from the person that has lanteam 1 in the database. And I can use an else to output the gamertags from the second team.

```
require '../includes/dbh.inc.php';
$sql = "SELECT lanteam, gamertag FROM gebruikers WHERE lanteam=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Je zit in team 1, je captain is Martijn";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Je teamgenoten zijn: ";
    while (($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        echo '<p class="rtg-teamgenoten">' . $data['gamertag'] . '</p>';
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```